# Can Envers use a different database?

Tags: hibernate-envers

Is possible for Hibernate Envers to use another database for audit tables?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a different schema/catalog. See the `org.hibernate.envers.default_schema` and `org.hibernate.envers.default_catalog` configuration properties [1], as well as the `schema`/`catalog` attributed of `@AuditTable`.

[1] http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html

Comment: adamw is this still the case today or has it changed since? Using a different DB might make sense to increase performance of the current DB especially if auditing is not a critical service.